# functions and multiple class hierarchy

Tags: c++

trying to understand methods and virtual function lets say i have 3 classes (the ones below)

```
class abstruct {void go()};

class animal:public abstruct {
           public:
           char* name;
           void go(){}
};

class bird:public abstruct {
           public:
           char* name;
           void fly(){}
};

class animalbird:public animal,public bird {
           void go(){}
};
```

my question is how can go function from animal be accessed in the `class animalbird`?? i tried just to write `void go(){}` but it seems im wrong.what am i doing wrong?

Comment: There is nothing virtual here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void animalbird::go() {
    animal::go();
}
```